# Combine three.js scene with webpage as a background

Tags: html, three.js

I have created two separate html documents. One where three.js scene is rendered and basic html page. My question is how can I correctly combine them ? My goal is to create rotating green cube in left corner and moving red cube, which would move from left side to right side. And red cube should be invisible when moving under grey content area.

**Three. js :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Cube_v2</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="build/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        //cube.position.x = 100;
        //cube.translateX = 100;
        //three.cube.position.x = 100;
        scene.add( cube );

        camera.position.z = 10;     
        camera.position.x = 10;

        var geometry_2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );
        var material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
        var cube_2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry_2, material_2 );
        scene.add( cube_2 );


        function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
        cube_2.position.x += 0.05;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        animate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Note:* i tried to move green cube with `cube.position.x` , `cube.translateX` and `three.cube.position.x` . But that didnt work so i fixed the issue by moving camera but i don't believe that's correct way of doing that.

**HTML** document where i want to import scene can be found here [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhy7mp6y/)

Comment: doing this could drastically decrease user experience. always keep in mind you should scale down three's resolution to keep it smooth on all devices not capable of rendering your scene in fullscreen. (yes, there are devices unable to handle their own resolution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to implement the three.js scene inside your webpage, make a div in the basic HTML page where you want it to be.

```
<div id="myScene"></div>
```

and in the script instead of:

```
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

write:

```
document.getElementById("myScene").appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Code snippet:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.getElementById("myScene").appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
//cube.position.x = 100;
//cube.translateX = 100;
//three.cube.position.x = 100;
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 10;    
camera.position.x = 10;

var geometry_2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );
var material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
var cube_2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry_2, material_2 );
scene.add( cube_2 );


function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
cube_2.position.x += 0.05;
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();
```

```css
canvas { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% 
}
.blue {
    color: #ffffff;  
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
   text-align: center;
   color: #ffffff;
}
.content {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:400px;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 121px);
}
.footer {
    color: #ffffff;  
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:30px;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
}
html {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div >
    <div class=blue>Header</div>
    <p style=color:red>LOGO</p>
    <div class="blue">Navigation Bar</div>
    <div id="myScene" class="content">
        Content.
        <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did as you said, but the three.js seems not to work or its being displayed somewhere else. I put all my code in pastebin. Could you maybe please go through it ? Link : https://pastebin.com/SbLPhCKk . Thank you.